# Simple directory listing java program doesn't compile un JDK 1.7

Tags: java, sql

I have this very simple code that looks for XML files in a given path and then inserts the filenames and ID in a table. It works perfectly when the Oracle DB uses OJVM 1.6 but when the DB had been patched and switch the OJVM version to JDK7 (1.7) it simply doesn't compile.

Can anyone give me any help about where is the problem, thanks.

```
create or replace and compile java source named "DirList"  as
import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;

   public class DirList
    {
        public static void getList(String directory) throws SQLException
        {
            File path = new File( directory );
            String[] list = path.list();
            String element;
            Integer id;

            if (list != null)
            {

                for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i].indexOf(".xml")>0 || list[i].indexOf(".XML")>0){
                        element = list[i];
                        id = i + 1;
                        #sql { INSERT INTO files (ID, SFILE)
                                                       VALUES (:id, :element) };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
/
```

I've forgot to add the compile error output:

```
SQL> show error java source "DirListTable";
Errors for JAVA SOURCE "DirListTable":

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0  An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_221). Please
     file a bug at the Java Bug Database
     (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) after checking the
     database for duplicates. Include your program and the following
     diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.

0/0  at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:322)
0/0  at sun.io.CharToByteCp1252.<init>(CharToByteCp1252.java:48)
0/0  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown
     Source)


LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0  at
     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Delegat
     ingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)

0/0  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
0/0  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java)
0/0  at sun.io.Converters.newConverter(Converters.java)
0/0  at sun.io.Converters.newConverter(Converters.java)
0/0  at
     sun.io.CharToByteConverter.getConverter(CharToByteConverter.java)


LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0  at
     sqlj.util.io.UCode_CharStream.<init>(UCode_CharStream.java:169)

0/0  at
     sqlj.util.io.UCode_CharStream.<init>(UCode_CharStream.java:181)

0/0  at sqlj.syntax.JSParser.<init>(JSParser.java:43)
0/0  at sqlj.javac.JavaParserSub.<init>(JavaParserSub.java:68)
0/0  at sqlj.translator.Translator.setOptions(Translator.java:124)
0/0  at sqlj.framework.ide.Translator.<init>(Translator.java:51)
0/0  at

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
     sqlj.framework.ide.aurora.SqljTranslator.init(SqljTranslator.java
     )

0/0  at
     oracle.aurora.jdkcompiler.SqljInterface$TransformedSqljSource.get
     Translated(SqljInterface.java:301)

0/0  at
     oracle.aurora.jdkcompiler.SqljInterface$TransformedSqljSource.get
     Stream(SqljInterface.java:363)


LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0  at
     oracle.aurora.compiler.ExternalEntityJavaFileObject.openInputStre
     am(ExternalEntityJavaFileObject.java:60)

0/0  at
     oracle.aurora.compiler.ExternalEntityJavaFileObject.getCharConten
     t(ExternalEntityJavaFileObject.java:115)

0/0  at
     com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.jav
     a:997)

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------

0/0  at
     com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:8
     93)

0/0  at
     com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java)

0/0  at oracle.aurora.jdkcompiler.JdkDriver.compile(JdkDriver.java)
0/0  at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler.doCompile(Compiler.java:670)
0/0  at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler.access$000(Compiler.java:57)

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0  at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:324)
0/0  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
0/0  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What are you trying to do with the `#sql` statement?

Comment: With the #sql I've trying to insert and id and the file name in a table with two columns ID (number) and SFILE (Varchar2). The error is now in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think the error you are getting is on sql statements ?
You can try using prepared statement and then insert in DB

Comment: Yes, but with no luck.
I've already try to modify the #sql insert with hardcoded values and doesn't compile neither.